# How to use a google sheets pivot query to output strings

Tags: sql, google-sheets, pivot

I have a (much larger) table like this sample:

[image: Original Data]

I am trying to output a table that looks like this:

[image: Desired Outcome]

The closest I can get with a pivot query returns numerical results in the value fields, rather than the desired text strings

```
=query(Data, "Select D,count(D) group by D Pivot B")
```

I resorted to a series of formulas to build my row and column headers, and then fill in the data field - See Version 3 in the [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hYFQ-LqsqKs-aIIv0Xzrf-vSPiZ7b13l6c5YTn-vpKw/edit#gid=0).  But I couldn't figure out how to fill in the data with a single formula - as opposed to copying and pasting in the data field, which is not desirable with a dynamic number of row and column headers based on the original data.

Is there a way to wrap my data field formula (in cell B44 of the sample) in an arrayformula that will fill the data field, with a dynamic number of columns and rows?

Or even more advanced is there a formula that will deliver my desired results table in a single formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, it's a bit difficult to explain, but i could demonstrate the various parts if you opened up your sheet to editable...

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY({CHAR(10)&A2:A11,B2:B11&"|"&D2:D11&"|"},"select MAX(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2"),,9^9)),"|",0,0)),"select Col1,MAX(Col3) where Col1<>'' group by Col1 pivot Col2 order by Col1 desc label Col1'Project'")))
```

Comment: the department sort on mine however is happening because Producing, Directing and Acting - 1,2,3 happens to be reverse alpha.  I'd need to modify the formula to account for your "sort" column.

Comment: That is a remarkably brief formula.  I suspect I could reverse engineer the parts.  But if you wouldn't mind demonstrating it would probably be helpful for future folx who find this question.

Comment: Also, I notice that the project sort isn't quite explicitly what I am looking for, but I suspect that is not a terribly difficult change.

Comment: I forgot to say...THANKS.

Comment: @DHolcomb the two sorting orders are trickier than you might imagine, i'm gonna try to do something, but it would be easier if the Project order was ALSO numbers rather than letters.  is that a possible change you can make?

Comment: @DHolcomb I put a new version on your opened-up sample sheet on the tab called Reorg_mpk.  It will work for up to 9999 unique projects.  More than that and it would need a small edit.